# Complex analytic function.

Tags: complex-analysis

There is a theorem as below

Suppose $f$ is continuous in an open set $D$ and analytic there except possibly at the points of a line segment $L.$ Then $f$ is analytic throughout $D.$

Its proof is given in Bak and Newman book at page number 87. Now my question is can I extend the above result if I replace the line segment by a portion of a curve inside $D?$ That is can I say that

$f$ is continuous in an open set $D$ and analytic there except possibly at the points of a curve. Then $f$ is analytic throughout $D.$ Please help me . Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by curve?  If you just mean a continuous image of $[0,1]$, then a space-filling curve gives a counter-example.

Comment: how counterexample?

Comment: Take a space-filling curve which fills the unit disk $D$ and any function which is continuous but not analytic on $D$.  Then $f$ satisfies your conditions but isn't analytic.  So, at the very least, we'd need to restrict to something like one-to-one curves for this to have a shot at being true.

Comment: not space fitting curve.. I m saying like a portion of a circle...I don't know what to say this type of curve..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace the line segment by a rectifiable curve (having finite length), with essentially the same proof, using Morera's theorem.

But it is not true with arbitrary curve. Not even speaking of space-filing curves,
it is relatively simple to construct a counterexample if the curve has positive area. The precise characterization of curves for which this is true is the famous problem of Paul Painleve, and no simple characterization can be given.